# Change the App Store country to India?

Tags: ios-appstore

I am in China and bought an iPhone 4s here. It has been updated to iOS 8.1.2 . I want to change the App Store country from China to India.

How do I do this?

Comment: When you are in app store is there a circle with Flag of the country at bottom right corner?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have an apple id located in India (address). When you log in to the app store, you probably get a message that the app is going to load another store. When this is done, you're in the appstore for India.